# Prove that there's no decidable language that separates two other languages.

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, computability, turing-machines, decidability

I was reviewing for an exam and I found this question:
Let A and B be two disjoint languages (that is, A ∩ B = ∅). Say that a language C separates A
and B iff A ⊆ C and B ⊆ (not C) .
Define two disjoint languages by

A = {⟨M,w⟩: M is a TM and M accepts w}

B = {⟨M,w⟩: M isaTMandM rejects w}

Prove that there does not exist any decidable language C that separates A and B.

I guess the way the proof has to be made is by contradiction. If we were able to built a decidable language  C that separates A and B then we would be able to use that decision as a black box to decide A={<M,w>| M is a TM and M accepts w}, that we know that's undecidable, and this would be a contradiction. But could someone elaborate this reduction? I have been thinking on it for days. Thanks

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't the language of *all* words, using the appropriate alphabet, contain both $A$ and $B$ trivially? It sounds like this language will separate any two languages using this alphabet. Is there something missing from the definition?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

If $C$ is decidable, then the questions ''$x\in A$'' or ''$x\in B$'' must be decidable since $C$ has the separation property. But these questions are not decidable due to the halting problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more your answer?